# Number of squares between two natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Given natural numbers $m>n\in \mathbb{N}$ how many squares are between $m$ and $n$? i.e., how many natural numbers $k\in \mathbb{N}$ satisfy that $n \leq k^2\leq m$?

I think that if we were to know the largest square $k^2=s\leq m$ and the smallest square $\tilde k^2=\tilde{s}\geq n$, then the number of squares I am looking for would be $k-\tilde{k}+1$, but is there a simple way to find these squares? I would be okay with a bounds which are functions of the size $m-n$.

Comment: The smallest square in this range is $\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil^2$ and the largest square in this range is $\lfloor \sqrt{m} \rfloor^2$.

Comment: You are essentially conunting the no of integers between $\sqrt n$ and $\sqrt m$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of squares between two natural numbers $m$ and $n$ = $\begin{align} \lfloor \sqrt{m} \rfloor - \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil + 1\end{align}$.

**Proof:**
Let $\begin{equation} n \leq a^2 \leq k^2 \leq (a+s)^2 \leq m \end{equation}$ where $a$ is the smallest natural number whose square is greater than or equal to $n$ and $a+s$ is the largest natural number whose square is less than or equal to m.

Now, from simple observation, $\begin{equation} a = \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil \end{equation}$ and $\begin{equation} a+s = \lfloor \sqrt{m} \rfloor \end{equation}$ and the number of squares between the two natural number is $s+1$.